# Is $A$ convex if and only if $-\ln(i_{A})$ is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

Is it correct that we have : $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex if and only if $-\ln(i_{A})$ is a convex function? 
where here $i_A$ takes the value 1 at $x \in A$ and $+\infty$ elsewhere.

I have found this statement a little bit weird since one knows that we usually compose with an nondecreasing convex function to construct convex functions where here -ln is nonincreasing convex.

Comment: Instead I propose A convex if and only if $ln(i_A)$ convex which can be easily proved using that $epi(ln(i_A))=A \times \mathbb{R}$

Comment: What's $A$? The question is rather unclear.

Comment: to Benjamin Lindqvist : Thank you for your response. $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$